# Git: how to remove root commit

Tags: git

I have following situation in my local Git repository:
master: A---B---C <-HEAD
(no name): D

so there is special commit "D" on separate branch, not relating on any other branch. I want to delete the "(no name)" branch. When trying to revert "D", I get: "Cannot revert a root commit".

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no branch that reference D, then git will remove the reference when you do a garbage collection.

Comment: Reflog entries can prevent the pruning of objects that are not reachable from any ref (HEAD, branch, tag, etc.)—see the `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` configuration variables. Also, “young” objects are kept by default—see the `gc.pruneExpire` configuration variable. So, the user may need to expire reflog entries and force the pruning of young objects with something like `git reflog --expire-unreachable=now --all && git gc --prune=now` (or, better, “manually” delete just the responsible reflog entries with (e.g.) `git reflog delete HEAD@{3}`).

Answer (score 0):

What Casey said. Run "git gc" and see if it still exists. The other thing you might want to try is create a new branch at D and then remove the branch with git -D